# Update More Than One Column Failing in DB2i Merge Statement

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

Forum.

I am working with IBM System i Version 7.1.

I am running into a issue when updating more than one column in a merge statement.

The following statement works when setting one column:

```
merge into database.table as t 
                 using ( values( 
    cast(99 as smallint) 
    ,cast('dave' as varchar(40))
                 )) 
                 as caz(
    group_id
    , group_name
    ) 
                 on t.group_id = caz.group_id 
                 when matched then update
    set t.group_name = caz.group_name
                 when not matched then 
                 insert (
    group_id
    , group_name
    ) 
                 values (
    caz.group_id
    , caz.group_name
    );
```

The same statement no longer works when I add an additional set line:

```
merge into database.table as t 
                 using ( values( 
    cast(99 as smallint) 
    ,cast('dave' as varchar(40))
    ,cast(1 as smallint)     
                 )) 
                 as caz(
    group_id
    , group_name
    , queued_calls_above_tasa
    ) 
                 on t.group_id = caz.group_id 
                 when matched then update
    set t.group_name = caz.group_name,
    set t.queued_calls_above_tasa = caz.queued_calls_above_tasa
                 when not matched then 
                 insert (
    group_id
    , group_name
    , queued_calls_above_tasa
    ) 
                 values (
    caz.group_id
    , caz.group_name
    , caz.queued_calls_above_tasa
    );
```

I get the following error message:

> > merge into database.table as t                   using ( values(      cast(99 as smallint)      ,cast('dave' as varchar(40))     ,cast(1 as
> >     smallint)                       ))                   as caz(
> >     group_id     , group_name     , queued_calls_above_tasa     )
> >     on t.group_id = caz.group_id                   when matched then
> >     update     set t.group_name = caz.group_name,     set
> >     t.queued_calls_above_tasa = caz.queued_calls_above_tasa
> >     when not matched then                   insert (     group_id     ,
> >     group_name     , queued_calls_above_tasa     )
> >     values (     caz.group_id     , caz.group_name     ,
> >     caz.queued_calls_above_tasa     )
>
> SQL State: 42601
>   Vendor Code: -104
>   Message: [SQL0104] Token T was not valid. Valid tokens: =. Cause . . .
>   . . :   A syntax error was detected at token T.  Token T is not a
>   valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is =.  This list assumes
>   that the statement is correct up to the token.  The error may be
>   earlier in the statement, but the syntax of the statement appears to
>   be valid up to this point. Recovery  . . . :   Do one or more of the
>   following and try the request again: -- Verify the SQL statement in
>   the area of the token T. Correct the statement.  The error could be a
>   missing comma or quotation mark, it could be a misspelled word, or it
>   could be related to the order of clauses. -- If the error token is
>   , correct the SQL statement because it does not end
>   with a valid clause.
>
> Processing ended because the highlighted statement did not complete
>   successfully

Any help is appreciated.

Please let me know if I may provide more information.

Comment: What do you mean by no longer works? Do you get an error, or you don't get the expected result?

Comment: Thanks for that; I edited the question to include the error message details I had received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the second 'set' allows it to succeed as follows:

```
merge into database.table as t 
                 using ( values( 
    cast(99 as smallint) 
    ,cast('dave' as varchar(40))
    ,cast(1 as smallint)     
                 )) 
                 as caz(
    group_id
    , group_name
    , queued_calls_above_tasa
    ) 
                 on t.group_id = caz.group_id 
                 when matched then update
    set t.group_name = caz.group_name,
    t.queued_calls_above_tasa = caz.queued_calls_above_tasa
                 when not matched then 
                 insert (
    group_id
    , group_name
    , queued_calls_above_tasa
    ) 
                 values (
    caz.group_id
    , caz.group_name
    , caz.queued_calls_above_tasa
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

@HappyCoding is correct, you only need one `SET` statement.

Another alternative for the `WHEN MATCHED`:

```
when matched then update
    set (t.group_name, t.queued_calls_above_tasa) 
          = (caz.group_name, caz.queued_calls_above_tasa )
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Regarding our answers and software best practices, do you know if one format is preferred more than the other?

Comment: The alternative format is newer and known as a **Row Value Constructor (RVC)**  or [Row Value Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/row-value-expression/info)  Support might be a bit hit or miss if you're trying to write code that uses multiple DBs

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Charles. I also found the following article as a good reference: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/row-value-constructor

Comment: @HappyCoding...note that that site caters to MS SQL Server, not DB2.  Although in this particular instance, the article is  more applicable to DB2 since MS SQL Server doesn't have the RVC support.